# About TLS/SSL , why should Pre_master_secret be deleted at once?

Tags: ssl

I know MASTER_SECRET which can be stored in memory is for session resumption and KEY is for each connection.[RFC 5246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-8.1) says PRE_MASTER_SECRET should be deleted from memory once the master_secret has been computed. But why?

Answer (score 0):

Because it is not needed anymore but can be used to calculate master_secret. So getting it from memory in any way can allow to decrypt all the traffic.

Comment: No,I don't think so. PMS is computed for EACH session during handshaking, so getting it from memory can allow to decrypt ONLY one session but not all the traffic. In some cases,PMS may be the same for different sessions(i.e. key exchange by fixed DH or RSA with an encryption key). Delete PMS than use MS to protect those sessions?

Comment: Sorry, under 'all taffic' I meant exactly 'one session's traffic'. That's a security threat, since you can first catch all session's traffic, make memory dump (all automatically), and after that spend some time to search for PMS, decryption, whatever else.

Comment: Now PMS is deleted, if I search for MS, I can do decryption too. So deleting PMS is not to protect the session. Right? @nickolay

Answer (score 0):

Assume it uses PMS but not MS as the session key.

1. PMS **could** be the same for all the sessions(because it's a random number).
2. We must store all the session keys in memory for session resumption.
3. The session key in memory may be compromised, then all the sessions uses the same key will be cracked.

`PMS -> KEY` vs `PMS -> MS -> KEY`(with nonreversible hash)

To make sure damage limited to one session, we take one more step. Create and store MS as the session key, then delete PMS at once.